# How to merge multiple workbook's 1st column into a worksheet of different workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy Column A data from multiple workbooks (only 1st sheet) (All the source files will have a different name but same extension) and consolidate them into one worksheet in the Master workbook with a condition that the copy should exclude the header rows from all the source files and the rows should be pasted starting from row 8, column E in the master workbook (as I need to keep range (rows 1-7 & columns A-D) static in the master workbook). SO far whatever I tried I failed.

I have tried the below code but it seems, it is not what I wanted to have. I mean it is copying worksheets and pasting them individually in the master workbook.

```
Path = "F:\REPORTS\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

For Each Workbook In Workbooks
  If Workbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
  Workbook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
  ActiveSheet.Name = Workbook.Name 
  End If
  Next
  Set Workbook = Nothing
  Workbooks(Filename).Close
  Filename = Dir()
  Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Take a look at the questions under "Related" on this page...  This task comes up here regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I figured out the solution, here I need to not provide the file extension details. 
the requirement is slightly modified.. here I am trying to copy only the 1st column from all the source worksheets into a master workbook.

```
Function ImportData()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("F:\FILES")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

Range("A2:A" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Function
```